# Flash Builder 4 is suggesting mx1 instead of mx! why?

Tags: apache-flex, namespaces, flash-builder

I just bought and installed the Flash Builder 4 after having the Beta for a while. The same code is giving me compile-time errors and suggests using mx1 instead of mx! If I make it mx1 the compile error goes away. Here is the top of my component:

```
<s:SkinnableContainer   xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
```

I mentioned nothing about mx1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used:

```
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
```

instead of:

```
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
```

and it worked.